# update SQL table with multiple arrays using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I would like to update a `SQL` table using `PHP` with `PDO`. However I keep getting the following error

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\core\functions\update_projects.php on line 31
```

I just can't make sense of where I'm going wrong.

```
    $j = 1;
    $chunk_count = count($update)/7;
    $backwards = array_reverse($update);
    $chunks = array_chunk($backwards, 7);

    var_dump($chunks[1]);       

    try {
        for($i = 0; $i < $chunk_count; $i++ ) {
            $update_project = $db->prepare('
                UPDATE projects
                SET comments = ?,
                    contact = ?,
                    est_end = ?,
                    est_start = ?,  
                    apm = ?,  
                    pm = ?                              
                WHERE id = ?
            ');

            foreach ($chunks[$i] as $field => $val) {               
                $update_project->bindValue($j++, $val, PDO::PARAM_STR);                                 
            }
            $update_project->execute();
        }   

        echo 'Projects Updated';        

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
```

If I `var_dump($chunks[1])` I see the following values

```
array(7) { [0]=> string(13) "some comments" [1]=> string(7) "jim doe" [2]=> string(6) "1-1-14" [3]=> string(7) "12-1-13" [4]=> string(8) "jane doe" [5]=> string(7) "jon doe" [6]=> string(2) "16" }
```

So where is the problem in my code? Any help is appreciated

Comment: someone deleted the correct answer. If I change `i = 0` to `i = 1` it works, but I'm curious as to why. Shouldn't `$chunks` start at a 0 index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true, SQL parameters start numbering from 1 (I don't know why the owner of that answer deleted it).

The parameter numbering is defined in the SQL/CLI standard, which dates back to the 1980's, before the number zero was invented. ;-)

---

As for why your code isn't updating, I'd look to make sure the id values are positioned where you expect them.  After reversing and chunking the array, if the id value doesn't end up in the right spot, it might try to update rows, but match none.

Here's an alternative way to code this routine:

```
$backwards = array_reverse($update);
$chunks = array_chunk($backwards, 7);

var_dump($chunks[1]);       

try {
    $update_project = $db->prepare('
        UPDATE projects
        SET comments = ?,
            contact = ?,
            est_end = ?,
            est_start = ?,  
            apm = ?,  
            pm = ?                              
        WHERE id = ?
    ');
    $n = 0;
    foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
        $update_project->execute($chunk);
        $n += $update_project->rowCount();
    }   

    echo 'Projects Updated, affected $n rows';        

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: lol, well fantastic. Thanks for the explanation and the humor.

Comment: This may be a little late, but this is actually only a partial solution. You see if I change `$i = 1` it only changes the first chunk of values. The chunks actually represent rows, as I'm sure you assumed. So this is only updating the first row. The 2nd is not being set. Any idea why?

Comment: Nevermind, this works perfect, I had a small error on my end that I caught. Thanks!