# PDO update only updating one row

Tags: php, pdo

So I am quite confused by this problem. I am sending a post to this `PHP` file using `AJAX` and it takes my array, reverses it, chunks it and then uses it to bind values. Each chunk holds a row worth of info to update, so each iteration of the for loop updates a row.

The first time I attempted this I used the following code.

```
if(isset($_POST['saveEdits'])) {
    $i = 0;
    $j = 1; 
    $update = array();          
    $update = $_POST['saveEdits'];
    $chunk_count = count($update)/7;    
    $backwards = array_reverse($update);
    $chunks = array_chunk($backwards, 7);               

    try {
        for($i; $i < $chunk_count; $i++ ) {
            $update_project = $db->prepare('
                UPDATE projects
                SET comments = ?,
                    contact = ?,
                    est_end = ?,
                    est_start = ?,  
                    apm = ?,  
                    pm = ?                              
                WHERE id = ?
            ');

            foreach ($chunks[$i] as $field => $val) {                           
                $update_project->bindValue($j++, $val, PDO::PARAM_STR);                                 
            }           
            $update_project->execute();

        }

        echo 'Projects Updated';        

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }   
} else {    
    echo 'could not update projects table';
}
```

and I would get the following error each time

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\core\functions\update_projects.php on line 31
```

so it was suggested that I change

```
$i = 0;
```

to

```
$i = 1;
```

This somehow works. This lets me insert the data one time, but does not insert all of the data. The fact that this works *at all* is baffling to me. $i is the holder for my loop index, and chunks index. It needs to go from 0 - whatever. I don't understand how starting at 1 helps in any way. $j is the holder for the param binder, which *should* start at 1.

Some additional info. If I var_dump(chunks[0]) and var_dump(chunks[1]) I see the following

```
array(7) { [0]=> string(13) "more comments" [1]=> string(9) "jimmy doe" [2]=> string(6) "1-1-14" [3]=> string(7) "12-1-13" [4]=> string(9) "janey doe" [5]=> string(9) "jonny doe" [6]=> string(2) "17" } 
array(7) { [0]=> string(13) "some comments" [1]=> string(7) "jim doe" [2]=> string(6) "1-1-14" [3]=> string(7) "12-1-13" [4]=> string(8) "jane doe" [5]=> string(7) "jon doe" [6]=> string(2) "16" }
```

So review. `$i = 0` and I get the error up top, `$i = 1` I get to insert one row and it's over. Can someone please tell me what's going on here? Any help is appreciated

Comment: can you paste full code? html?

Comment: i like that i get a down vote with no explanation *after* I answer my own question.

Comment: A param wasn't defined. What more do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code. The main issue though is the way you are attempting to split up the array into chunks. Let's say you have 10 items in your array, given your code `$chunk_count = count($update)/7;`, this would give us a chunk count of 1.4285..., greater than 1, but less than 2. Then in your loop, I would expect it to run only once if `$i = 1;` because the first time through the loop, 1 < 1.x, but the second time 2 > 1.x.

What are you trying to accomplish by breaking up this array? Just process it straight through. Remember to Keep It Simple when possible.

Comment: This array will always be multiples of 7. So that's why I divide by 7. There will never be a remainder. It will always be a whole number. You can see the process at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NuLPC/8/. Basically I have an editable table, when the user is done a loop stores all the data in an array. Then I need to break the array up so that I can bind the values. If you have a better solution please let me know. I don't think this is pretty, it just works

Comment: plus you're answer does not explain *why* it would insert the value one time and not another by starting the loop at 1 instead of 0 and that is quite honestly what bothers me about this problem

Comment: +1 I get it now. You can see that in my answer. I was so frustrated with the *why* last night I never stopped to think about the *how*.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it simple. Here is what worked for me. This still left me wondering about the original problem, but oh well.

```
$backwards = array_reverse($update);
$chunks = array_chunk($backwards, 7);
$n = 0;         

try {
    $update_project = $db->prepare('
        UPDATE projects
        SET comments = ?,
            contact = ?,
            est_end = ?,
            est_start = ?,  
            apm = ?,  
            pm = ?                              
        WHERE id = ?
    ');

    foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
        $update_project->execute($chunk);
        $n += $update_project->rowCount();
    }   

    echo 'Projects Updated, affected ' . $n . ' rows';        

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Credit to this answer goes to Bill Karwin [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984311/update-sql-table-with-multiple-arrays-using-pdo)

Comment: Why would you down vote this answer? Not only does it work, it does what the only other answer suggests.